# Editing MST files using ORCA

Tags: windows

Our MST files for office 2003 (v11.0) contains an old exchange server address. I've downloaded the Microsoft SDK, and ran Orca to open the MST files for both Office and Outlook.
Opening and editing them went fine, but upon save I notice that my newly saved MST file was 5KB, where the original file is around 58KB. 
In Orca, I can spot no difference between the newly 5KB MST and the old 58KB, but upon replacing the MST files on the server for remote installation, new windows clients no longer gets neither Office nor Outlook installed.
It's pretty obvious that the file somehow gets corrupted/incomplete, so my question is: 
How can I successfully open and edit the MST files, in order to save them with all data needed to allow new clients to not only have office and outlook installed, but have the correct server address for the exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick is to open the MSI, not the MST, with an MSI editor, generate transcript (MST), edit, save.